# Visual debugger for JRuby on the mac?

Tags: debugging, user-interface, ide, jruby

Our organisation is starting move our development efforts from the ASP.NET stack to JRuby (on rails & sinatra mostly).

I'm quite happy editing, running tests and other day to day operations in VIM and find it much faster than heavy visual studio style IDEs.

One thing I do miss is the debugger in visual studio and being able to add a break point and hover over variables to see their values etc.

I also find it incredibly handy being able to "step into" other peoples code when i'm first getting acquainted with it to see how things actually work!

I'm on the mac, what are my options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns our [rubymine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/) does pretty much everything i've been looking for,
used successfully to step through active record :)